# MySQL - How to query items by tags, order by matched tag count

Tags: mysql, sql, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

My schema looks something like this:

```
items ( id, title, blah )
tags (id, name )
item_tags ( item_id, tag_id )
```

I want to list all items, where the item's tags are "in" an array of selected tags, and then order by the number of tags that match the selection (e.g. [1, 2, 3])

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(item_tags.tag_id) AS tag_count
FROM items
JOIN item_tags
ON item_tags.item_id = items.id
WHERE item_tags.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY items.id
ORDER BY tag_count DESC
```

This works well, except the tag_count just gets the total number of tags for the item selected, i want it be the number of tags selected that are contained in (1, 2, 3).

An item with tags (1, 2, 3) should come before an item with tags (1, 5, 6, 7).

I am using Kohana 3's ORM if there is a solution that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your SELECT to:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS tag_count
.....
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you really want is a GROUP_CONCAT( tag_id ) (maybe in addition to your count).  The group concat will concatinate your IDs such as you've shown... 1, 2, 3 and 1, 5, 6, 7.  If you use THAT column as your order by, you should be good.

Now, that said, you might have to force some formatting of the concatination process to handle things like 1, 10, 100 coming before 1, 2, 3.  As such, if formatting the concatinated ID strings to say... 2 or 3 positions, you would get

```
001, 002, 003 
vs
001, 005, 006, 007 
vs
001, 010, 100
```

HTH

Comment: -1 A group concat wouldn't change the fact that the number of grouped rows (currently represented by `COUNT(*)`) is wrong. It will, as you point out, only create additional sorting problems.

Comment: It might, however, be a good idea to use a `GROUP_CONCAT` to debug your SQL. By adding something like `CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id SEPARATOR ',') AS CHAR)` to the `SELECT` statement, it should be possible to see exactly which tags are counted for each item.

Comment: Thanks for that - I can now see more clearly that my original query is working how I had planned

Comment: @Tom, glad to hear that my solution offered help... Sometimes, by looking into other alternatives can open your eyes to what SQL is doing behind the scenes and THEN remove the "debug" columns used for analysis (@Ivar Bonsaksen)

Comment: @Ivar, DRapp Yeah the GROUP CONCAT is definitely useful there. That column seems to be useful for showing to the end user which tags are matched to the items listed without having to do a separate query on each item (I'd need a separate query of course to show the tag's name) - do you think GROUP CONCAT is a viable solution there?